# How do you efficiently develop/test locally then launch on a production server?

Tags: php, testing, web-applications

I have a problem on deciding how to effectively develop and test web applications, then launch them on a production server. I am very new to web development, and also developing large projects in general, so please bear with me.

I am going to host my web application on a VPS running Debian 7 32-bit. On this VPS, I use PHP 5.4.16 and nginx from dotdeb. What I want to do is to get a local machine that uses exactly the same packages and configurations so that launching on a production server is easy. I once had a nightmare adjusting various settings that worked in my development machine, but not on productions. Maybe this approach is not a right thing to do. Should I allocate part of the production server for development and testing? But I would need to be ssh-ing all the time.

Another problem is that even if I could get the same packages on my local machine, what if I need to use different version of PHP in the future? What if I need to install packages that are not compatible other packages installed?

Only solution seems to maintain a virtual machine for each project. Is this a decent solution? How do you efficient develop/test on local development machines?

Comment: I don't do PHP dev so I can't comment on that. Personally, I run a variant of Ubuntu on my dev laptop, and use Ubuntu on all my VPSs, so there is no incompatibility there. I use the Ruby language, with a "version manager" which lets me switch the version of Ruby + all Ruby libraries used at will. I have my shell set up so that `cd`ing into a project directory automatically selects the version of Ruby+libraries used by that project. Then, I run both MySQL+Postgres on my dev machine, so each project can run locally against the same DB as in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have several different problems to address: development, testing, deployment into production, monitoring production.

Normally you want to do development on equipment that is separated from production using data and an environment that is similar to production yet has all of the nice things that development needs to be efficient and effective such as test harnesses, debuggers, loggers, automated unit testing, etc. The data needs to something similar to what is in production but not production data since in most cases production data must be secured.  Also with development having its own manufactured data, it allows for the testing of specific scenarios as a part of designer test.

I would recommend having a standard test data set to which developers add as changes are made to the source code and functionality of the system. And the addition/modification of test data is a change that needs some kind of formal or semi-formal process with some thought behind it or you will end up with a mess. Entropy is real for software systems just as it is for physical systems tending towards chaos and disarray.

The testing environment needs to be separated from the development environment and to be as close a representation of the production environment as possible.  You probably want two versions of the test environment, one for testing functionality with additional data capture to be used for a first pass verification in order to capture data development will need to fix problems found and a second that replicates production as closely as possible in order to get an idea as to efficiency issues.

Developers should not be allowed to put development tools onto the testing environment.  I have seen cases where something was rolled into production that crashed the system because a component was missing that the development environment provided.  You want to catch these kinds of issues in the testing environment.

Deployment of new system versions need to be planned so that you can roll back the changes if something goes wrong in production.

The main thing is to isolate production from development as much as possible so that you know exactly what is in the production servers. And when yo change what is on the production servers you have a pretty good idea as to what is changing and why and the effects of the changes on the production environment.

This is where the use of a repository such as Mercurial or Subversion places a quality control role. The idea is that what is in the repository is what goes into testing as a complete package. Once testing is completed on a particular package and the quality is good then the package goes into production.

This is also where you need to have a gold version of your production environment. In the interests of stability, you want your production environment to change in a controlled and methodical way. Everyone has seen an update come through that causes a previously working application and functionality to crash so you want to manage that process of updates.

So if you have a gold version of your production environment, an image of some kind then you can use that to replicate additional servers, your test environment, and your designer test environment. The additional variations of your production environment will have their own packages with the additions to the production environment that they need for instance the development environment would be the production environment plus the development environment with its tools, designer test data, etc.

This is where virtual machines are so handy.

This sounds laborious and inefficient and it is. However people make mistakes and this kind of a process helps to reduce the chance that a mistake will make it into production.

Answer (score 3):

This will lead to quite an opinionated response as everyone works differently, but here are some general rules to help you along:

1. Use version control and isolate your source code and your development and production environment requirements. This will help you in maintaining different versions and testing stuff out.
2. You can use [vagrant](http://vagrantup.com), which is like a "scriptable" virtual machine controller to easily manage replicated environments.
3. For your own sanity, make sure the database versions across your environments are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This very much depends on a few factors:

1. How much say you have on the OS of your hosting environment
2. What access you have to said hosting environment
3. What technologies you want to use on your projects (assuming PHP for starters)

Assuming you can decide what OS you're hosting on, and have full access to that hosting environment (I would recommend both if you're still deciding on a host), then 3 is really the deciding factor.

[NginX](http://nginx.org) is a *very* good choice for web development, if only because it has very powerful abilities as a [proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule). You can run pretty much anything you want on the same server, and then [proxy](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule) it, or present it on a new [virtual host](http://wiki.nginx.org/ServerBlockExample) using NginX. (Yes, I know [Apache](http://www.apache.org/) has these features as well, but NginX seems to outperform Apache in almost every way). This is over and above it's abilities as a standalone server for both static and dynamic content. If you're not already familiar with PHP and NginX, check out [this link](http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration#PHP_via_FastCGI).

If you're using one frontend (in this case NginX) to present all of your projects on your hosting provider, then a virtual machine (you should be able to get away with one) that matches the OS (including version) of your hosting provider is a perfect development environment. From a practical standpoint, it doesn't really matter what VM solution you use, there are many from free to bank breaking. Pick one that fits the bill.

I'd also look into setting up a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). ([Git](http://git-scm.com/) is awesome, [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) is also awesome) for your projects. Don't be afraid of any perceived learning curves, these tools are *really* simple to get going with, and also *really* powerful once you're ready to use the power-tools.

You should also look into methods of transferring files between your development virtual machine and your web host. [SSH](http://www.openssh.org/) is the usual method these days, but I've heard of people using things like [BitTorrentSync](http://labs.bittorrent.com/experiments/sync.html) to keep their code bases in line. Personally, I think this is a bit risky (new tech, some unexpected behaviours etc.). If you're going SSH look into [Passwordless logins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Key_management). They aren't that hard to [set up](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/)!

With regards to PHP versions, if you *do* manage to come across incompatible package requirements, the easiest and cleanest solution is to run up another machine, There *are* ways around it (I leave that to you to Google), but I personally like to keep things separated. Honestly, it shouldn't come up too much.

Other than that, I can only say I hope you have fun doing web development! Don't be afraid to try your hand at other languages either; [Node.js](http://nodejs.org), [Python](http://python.org), [Go](http://golang.org) and many others are great fun to play around with on the server side, and Jquery, Angular.js and many others are awesome on the client side.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Each language has own tools for deployment. And especially this depends on environment you're using. I can give you example about medium environment (around 100 servers) web project/service. I'm a python developer, these types of tools were used in my team:

- Version control system (`git`, `mercurial`, `svn`) [production server had read-only access to repository)
- Virtual Environment tool (for python it's `virtualenv`, for ruby it's `rvm` and `bundler`, isolates python/ruby libraries and can use different versions of python/ruby itself)
- Configuration management tool (`puppet` is widely used one, which can setup all needed daemons like `nginx`, `uwsgi`, `mysql` database, `django` framework automated setup, `iptables` firewall, user management, ssh keys management)
- Makefile (for launching needed actions)

So basically having these 3 tools you can setup testing server identical to production within minutes. We gone even further, we had hypervizor on our server with API, so we could create devbox for any new developer within minutes, and we have plenty of contractors, same can be achieved with amazon instances. Of course you need to prepare your environment by writing scripts in puppet (or you can do it with bash if your environment not so huge), with plenty of configuration and so on.

This process called - [**Deployment**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_deployment).

For example what we did when we wanted to deploy changes from testing server to production server, we launched `make deploy production` command from production server, and script check-outed all the code from git, cleaned compiled python files, restarted nginx server, cleared cache and many other operations which is essential for applying our changes.

**Deployment** is considered as a skill, which mostly being done by team leaders, so they have to worry about server environment setup more than other developers. You probably will have policy on deployment. When you apply changes, it can be specific day of the week. There's nice video about this from facebook company: [video about deployment in facebook](https://www.facebook.com/video/video.php?v=10100259101684977).

My advice to use, google for every keyword from all of these answers. Deployment requires a lot time and effort for good reliable environment to setup. It's a valuable experience from all issues you ever had in production. I'm always reading news about trend solutions in IT, for example linkedin.com migrated to node.js recently (whole backend I think..). Here's some sources: [Hacker news](https://news.ycombinator.com/news), [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming), [High Scalability](http://highscalability.com/)

P.s. in php widely known deployment tool is capistrano, but I'd still would go with puppet and makefiles. It's just faster and more transparent.